# how to add object to another object using method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a following code,

```
var options = {
            'x': 250,
            'isVirtual': true,
          }

 var arr[0] = {
         'y': 250,              
  }
```

i need to add the options keys(instance) to arr[0].. how to add?

my expectation output is,

```
arr[0] = {
          'x': 250,
          'isVirtual': true,
          'y': 250,   
}
```

Comment: Use `options['y'] = 250;` or `options.y = 250;`. That's not an array it's an object. New properties can be added using `[]` or `.` notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Object.assign()`

```js
var arr = [];
var options = {
  'x': 250,
  'isVirtual': true,
}
arr[0] = {
  'y': 250,
}

Object.assign(arr[0], options);
console.log(arr[0])
```

Comment: Just a sidenote: Those are actual copies and not references.

Comment: Object.assign  thrown undefined

Comment: @Akbar Basha You can see at the bottom of page Browser compatibility https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign